# Getting import tilde (~) to work in a Visual Studio Asp.Net core angular template app

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, sass-loader

I am currently attempting to get a Material design theme to import in my Angular 5 application, which, at the moment, is the Asp.Net Core/MVC Angular template found in Visual Studio 2017, upgraded to the latest version of Angular (5.2.1).

I want to use the tilde method, as follows.

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

I am using webpack. 
I have an scss loader already installed. 
I have renamed my app.component.css file to app.component.scss and updated the reference. 
I have changed the encapsulation:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

I have tested that, and styles are applying.

Next I add the tilde prefixed import statement (repeated here for clarity).

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

It errors out with:

```
http://localhost:58963/~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css 404 (Not Found)
```

I also tried it by adding an alias into the webpack file:

```
resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
            "alias": {
                "~": path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
            }
        },
```

How do I get this to work in that environment?